# How to enable Swagger for API interfaces shared between NestJS and Angular within Nx monorepo?

Tags: angular, swagger, nestjs, nrwl-nx

I would like to enable Swagger for API interfaces, shared between NestJS and Angular app within an Nx monorepo. Is there a consistent and not workaround-looking way?

These are the approaches I haven't succeeded with:

#### Approach 1. Apply `@nestjs/swagger` decorators to the shared DTO classes

- create a new Nx monorepo with `npx create-nx-workspace@latest`
- select the `angular-nest` workspace blueprint
- install Swagger dependencies and bootstrap it according to the [guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger)
- add input of type `Message` in `app.component.ts` (doesn't make sense, just for testing):

```js
export class AppComponent {
  @Input() message: Message;

  hello$ = this.http.get<Message>('/api/hello');
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

- decorate `message` property with `ApiProperty()` in `api-interfaces.ts`:

```js
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class Message {
  @ApiProperty()
  message: string;
}
```

- run the NestJS app. It works fine, Swagger displays correct DTO structure in the Web view
- however, when I start the Angular app, I get errors:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/utils/load-package.util.js 8:39-59
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 81:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/@nestjs/mapped-types/dist/type-helpers.utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-transformer' in '.\node_modules\@nestjs\mapped-types\dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/cache/cache.providers.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cache-manager' in '.\node_modules\@nestjs\common\cache'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'class-transformer' in '.\node_modules\@nestjs\common\pipes'
...
```

Which looks like a bundling issue, similar to [this one](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1706). I haven't found any elegant working solution to fix it in Angular build.

#### Approach 2. Use [NestJS Swagger plugin](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger#plugin) and avoid decorators

This would be even a better way than the previous one, but it didn't work though. First, the Swagger plugin requires NestJS CLI, which is not the case in Nx monorepo. There's an [issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2147) suggesting some workarounds, but I haven't found them to be reliable enough and complete. Second, the plugin doesn't cover some important use cases, which still require decorators anyway. For instance:

```js
@ApiProperty({
  oneOf: [{ $ref: getSchemaPath(TypeA) }, { $ref: getSchemaPath(TypeB) }],
})
type: TypeA | TypeB;
```

And as described above, the decorators lead to errors.

#### Approach 3. Create interfaces out of DTO classes for dedicated use in the Angular app

What attracts me in this approach is the ability to abstract from the back-end specific logic, either Swagger, serialization, or validation decorators. We could do the following:

```js
// Expose to the back-end
export class MessageDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  message: string;
}

// Expose to the front-end
export interface Message extends MessageDto {}
```

In this case, the `Message` interface gets compiled well with the Angular app. But as soon as we introduce more complicated DTO compositions (classes with nested DTOs), this approach doesn't work.

I would appreciate any other ideas.

Comment: This might be a complete workaround (aka not a solution) is if you enable Swagger on the NestJS side then you might want to, instead of sharing the interfaces, use a 3rd party tool to generate the API stubs for the Angular side using tools like: nswag, swagger-codegen, ng-openapi-gen etc... These tools take in the `swagger.json` file as input

Comment: Thank you, @ChauTran! That's a good way to go unless I manage to make it working with the aforementioned stack. I'll dig deeper into the tools and the abilities to have them automated.

Answer (score 2):

I have succeeded of sharing DTO(s) between Angular and Nest.js (Approach #1)

Replacing `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser` to `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` has resolved the errors when building or serving the angular app.

See https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1706#issuecomment-474657479 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Martin's answer is most of the way there, but the situation may sometimes require the presence of these Swagger decorators in your models where certain metadata in the OpenAPI spec might not be expressible via inference using just the [cli plugin](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin) alone.

You *can* actually use the `@ApiXXX` decorators in your models, and still import them into your front-end Angular application directly.

To do this, you will use a shim provided by NestJS in the `@nestjs/swagger` package, along with a little Webpack-fu.

I am also using Nx (`16.0.3`), Angular (`15.2.8`), and NestJS (`^9.0.0`), so I will demonstrate with my own configurations.

- First, in your **front-end** app's `project.json` be sure you have your `build` target configured to use the `@nx/angular:webpack-browser` executor, and your `serve` target configured to use the `@nx/angular:webpack-dev-server` executor. For me, the `serve` target was the sticking point–I thought I was going crazy when my custom Webpack configuration wasn't being picked up, but it is an absolute requirement that you have *both* the `build` and `serve` targets configured using these executors.
- Be sure your webpack configuration is set up in your **front-end's** `project.json` file like so:

```json
{
// ... start of project.json
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/angular:webpack-browser",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/my-angular-app",
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "apps/my-angular-app/webpack.config.ts"
        }
      }
      // ... remainder of project.json
```

- Your **front-end** app's `webpack.config.ts` should look something like the following:

```js
import path from 'path';

export default function customConfig(config) {
  return {
    ...config,
    resolve: {
      ...config.resolve,
      alias: {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        // shims out nestjs swagger module in the frontend for DTO sharing
        '@nestjs/swagger': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/extra/swagger-shim')
      }
    }
  };
}
```

- Import your backend DTO into your front-end service, and enjoy not having to write the same model code twice!

#### Bonus

Additionally, the Swagger CLI Plugin mentioned by Martin can be used *at the same time* to take advantage of all of the other benefits it offers.

Assuming you're using the `@nx/webpack:webpack` executor to build your **back-end** service and the `@nx/js:js` executor for `serve`, you may configure the Swagger CLI Plugin like so:

```json
// ... start of project.json
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/webpack:webpack",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "defaultConfiguration": "production",
      "options": {
        // ... other options
        "webpackConfig": "apps/my-backend-app/webpack.config.ts",
        "transformers": [
          {
            "name": "@nestjs/swagger/plugin",
            "options": {
              "introspectComments": true
              // other plugin options here
            }
          }
        ]
        // ... other options
      }
      // ... remainder of project.json
```

To any future reader, please keep in mind that these executor names and options may change from one major version of Nx to another, but the core of the solution is to ensure you configure the `@nestjs/swagger` shims correctly in your **front-end** bundler, and that if you so desire, you set up the transformers to use the NestJS Swagger CLI Plugin for your **back-end** similar to the above.

Answer (score 0):

As easy workaround you may use ApiModelProperty decorator instead of ApiProperty:

```
import { ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger/dist/decorators/api-model-property.decorator';
```

ApiModelProperty does not cause cache-manager injection issues and the decorator will allow you to setup API documentation for DTO's.

Comment: Sorry to say that I tried this and I get the following error 

Module not found: Can't resolve '@nestjs/swagger/dist/decorators/api-model-property.decorator'

If I add the dependency, they'll ask for cache-manager dependency again :S

Answer (score 0):

In your second approach you propose to use the NestJS Swagger Plugin, but then claim that's not possible because it relies on the Nest CLI which NRWL doesn't use. While this is technically correct, it is still possible to achieve the same results by adding the Swagger Plugin to the webpack transformation pipeline that NX uses.

With the plugin in place, all your controllers, DTOs, etc. will be automatically annotated. For more advanced use cases, you can still manually add the desired decorators as the plugin will preserve them.

Below are the steps to add the NestJS Swagger Plugin to your NRWL NX project:

1. Open the `project.json` in the specific app where you want the
   NestJS Swagger Plugin to be active.
2. Locate the configuration for the `@nrwl/webpack:webpack` executor
3. Add `@nestjs/swagger/plugin` to the list of `transformers`.
4. (Optional) configure the plugin's settings like `introspectComments`

Below an example:

```json
{
    "name": "project-with-swagger-plugin",
    "targets": {
        "build": {
            "executor": "@nrwl/webpack:webpack",
            "options": {
                // other options 
                "transformers": [
                    // register plugins here
                    {
                        "name": "@nestjs/swagger/plugin",
                        "options": {
                            "introspectComments": true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        }
   }
}
```