# @nestjs/swagger and Angular in Nx monorepo: problem to share DTO

Tags: angular, nestjs, mapped-types, nestjs-swagger, nx-monorepo

Recently, we started a new project with Angular and NestJS inside a monorepo Nx, and it works great. However, when we want to use `@nestjs/swagger` features inside a shared lib called "DTO", things start to break.

Firstly, Angular didn't compile anymore. Hopefully, I found a good Stackoverflow post covering this subject and followed the recommandation: create a webpack config to shim out the @nestjs/swagger package with Angular builder (Source: [Post Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76213643/16774971))

Here is the custom webpack config:

```
import path from 'path';

export default function customConfig(config: any) {
    return {
        ...config,
        resolve: {
            ...config.resolve,
            alias: {
                ...config.resolve.alias,
                // shims out nestjs swagger module in the frontend for DTO sharing
                '@nestjs/swagger': path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    '../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/extra/swagger-shim'
                ),
            },
        },
    };
}
```

And now, it compiles !

But, some days later, I have another small problem: I'm unable to use `PartialType`, `OmitType`,... all the mapped-types described here: [Mapped Types NestJS/Swagger](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types)

The error when the DTO is loaded:
`TypeError: Class extends value () =\> {} is not a constructor or null`

And it points to this DTO:
`export class UpdateSpireDto extends PartialType(CreateSpireDto) {}`

Once I remove the `extends PartialType` method, it works correctly.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this ?

Or any recommandation of how to share DTO/models/... Between frontent (Angular) and backend (NestJS) inside Nx ?

I already considered to remove the PartialType method and use only the class with the properties, but it is not a good idea in a long term project. Using these mapped-types would be a great advantage for us.

I've already looked to these posts:

[How to use NX DTO libraries decorated with NestJS swagger api in frontend frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74939029/how-to-use-nx-dto-libraries-decorated-with-nestjs-swagger-api-in-frontend-framew)

[How to enable Swagger for API interfaces shared between NestJS and Angular within Nx monorepo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61720662/how-to-enable-swagger-for-api-interfaces-shared-between-nestjs-and-angular-withi)

But my problem does not come from the nestjs decorators, only the methods mapped-types...

Thank you in advance and have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Nxtivision I'v run today with the same issue.

For me it helped to update from "@nestjs/swagger": "7.1.1" to "@nestjs/swagger": "7.3.0".

I hope it helps You also.